# type GraphQl typegoose backend error while linking models error : Error: Prop-Option "ref"'s value is "null" or "undefined" for "User.projects" [E005]

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, graphql, typegoose

[user schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQjFv.png)

[projects schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK0LP.png)

I've  been able to fix it as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnVHZ.png)
however this doesn't seem like the right approach as Its throwing some warnings, also feels very make shift and like Its going to cause some bigger issues in future.
What I want is the cause of the problem and if there is anyother way to fix this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Next time you ask a question, please put the code as code blocks and not as pictures and you should also provide what package versions are used

---

For this error there is a documentation page, see [E005](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/error-warning-details#ref-is-undefined-e005).

In your case it looks like you have a "Circular Dependency" Problem, see [Reference other Classes: Circular Dependencies](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/reference-other-classes/#circular-dependencies) on how to fix this.

The Documentation Page basically says: "put all model compilation (`getModelForSchema` / `buildSchema` calls) into one file"

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I'll look into the docs!!

Comment: Thank you @hasezoey for mentioning the "Circular Dependency" problem and how to fix it!